# pass argc and argv to QApplication into unit test case method

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QtTest framework to test some functions which require `QApplication` to exist. So I want to write a method of my test case object like this:

```
void MyTestCase::testSomething()
{
    QApplication app(argc, &argv); // problem here - how to pass arc and argv
    callSomethingThatNeedsQApp();
    // app destroyed at the end of scope
}
```

By the problem is that I do not know how to instantiate `QApplication` without `argc` and `argv`. In my `main.cpp` I have:

```
{
    MyTestCase tc;
    status |= QTest::qExec(&tc, argc, argv);
}
```

So is there a way I can reach `argc` and `argv` from the body of the test case method `void MyTestCase::testSomething()` and use it to instantiate `QApplication`?

Comment: Could you just pass them into the constructor of MyTestCase where you could either copy them or keep references to them in your class and use them in testSomething()

Comment: @Ian4264 - Wow, the simplest solution! I must have been too tired to overlook this possibility - I feel a bit stupid now. :) Worth to make it a full answer. However until I read your suggestion I spent a while rewriting my original design and ended up with a solution which does not require `QApplication` for unit tests. The design is now much cleaner, with separated GUI and logic

Answer (score 2):

You can't create several applications while running the test. It's mentioned in the official doc:

> Only one application object should be created.

It also says:

> Warning: The data referred to by argc and argv must stay valid for the entire lifetime of the QApplication object. In addition, argc must be greater than zero and argv must contain at least one valid character string.

If you are planning to use the application in several test, probably you can create a singleton instance that holds the life of the application:

```
struct QtApp {
    auto& instance() {
         static auto argc = 1;
         static std::array<char*, 1> argv = {{ "my-app-name" }};
         static const QApplication app = QApplication(argc, argv.data());
         return app;
    }
}
```

Now, you just need to call it before using your tests or in the main app:

```
void MyTestCase::testSomething() {
    QtApp::instance();
    callSomethingThatNeedsQApp();
}
```

In your test functions, if you need access to the application instance, the official docs mention:

> The global qApp pointer refers to this application object. Only one application object should be created.

So you can use the `qApp` to access it or the singleton you just created.

Comment: I did not mean to create multiple instances of `QApplication` at the same time.  Each instance is destroyed at the end of the scope of each unit testing method. This is ho w I understand the docs. I cannot create multiple instances of `QApplication` in parallel but I can create them in a series. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I also do not like the idea of creating one instance which will serve all the tests. The reason is that the tests should be independent. I would prefer a fresh instance for each test.

Comment: Then, just create an instance in each test and keep your arguments alive. The only requirement is tú keep argc and argv alive while the rest is running.